# Calculating genus of a curve in positive characteristic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What methods of calculating the (geometric) genus of a curve in positive characteristic are there?

Based on a quick search, all that I can find is Riemann-Hurwitz-Hasse. It is not immediately clear to me if other standard methods (in characteristic 0) work equally well in the case of positive characteristic.

Comment: What "other standard methods" do you have in mind?

Comment: I guess just Riemann-Roch otherwise.
I guess the number of holomorphic n-forms on the variety defined by the curve can also be used in characteristic p, but I'd rather avoid that if possible.